# How do I get the month and day with leading 0's in SQL? (e.g. 9 => 09)

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
DECLARE @day CHAR(2)

SET @day = DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE())

PRINT @day
```

If today was the 9th of December, the above would print "9".

I want to print "09". How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Where is this being used? Ideally this should be done in the presentation layer if at all possible, but I'm sure we've all done something similar at some point or other...

Comment: I have a stored procedure that creates a folder structure in the file system and then i use the bcp utility to do a queryout which generates some text files. the names of the folder and text files are related to dates. so the mother folder would be 2012 (for the year). then \2012\201212\20121210\20121210 filename.txt

Comment: Have a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx ISO format 112 might make things easier.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**For SQL Server 2012 and up , with leading zeroes:**

```
 SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MM')
```

**without:**

```
SELECT    MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Comment: @twoleggedhorse yep, it's 2016 now :)

Comment: Most people do not have the latest version of SQL, a lot will still be on 2008 or less, so it is important to let them know when answers only work with specific versions.

Comment: As someone who is stuck on 2008 R2 at work, I always appreciate when people let me know which version of SQL server their code is for.

Answer (score 113):

Pad it with 00 and take the right 2:

```
DECLARE @day CHAR(2)

SET @day = RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE())), 2)

print @day
```

Comment: geeze, that code looks horrific! haha. but thanks. will give it a try.

Comment: I have updated it because I did a -1 inside the GETDATE() - Today is the 10th and I wanted the 9th so that I could test it...Use the updated code.

Comment: Out of curiosity, any particular reason for an NVARCHAR and the double zero?

Comment: Using CHAR will not work, you can use VARCHAR or NVARCHAR. I usually use nvarchar because I use unicode and it's a force of habit. Whenever I'm padding, I always use the same number of characters as the answer - just a personal preference, you can just use a single zero if you wish.

Comment: Okay, I think that's pretty smart!

Answer (score 25):

Use SQL Server's date styles to pre-format your date values.

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(2), GETDATE(), 101) AS monthLeadingZero  -- Date Style 101 = mm/dd/yyyy
    ,CONVERT(varchar(2), GETDATE(), 103) AS dayLeadingZero   -- Date Style 103 = dd/mm/yyyy
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this :

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(2), GETDATE(), 101)
```

Answer (score 7):

Leading 0 day

```
SELECT FORMAT(GetDate(), 'dd')
```

Answer (score 3):

**SQL Server 2012+** (for both month *and* day):

```
SELECT FORMAT(GetDate(),'MMdd')
```

If you decide you want the year too, use:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GetDate(),'yyyyMMdd')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Replicate('0',2 - DataLength(Convert(VarChar(2),DatePart(DAY, GetDate()))) + Convert(VarChar(2),DatePart(DAY, GetDate())
```

Far neater, he says after removing tongue from cheek.

Usually when you have to start doing this sort of thing in SQL, you need switch from can I, to should I.

Comment: Replicate!! That's the word I was looking for...I was thinking lpad, pad, couldn't remember for the life of me :)

Comment: I like your version better as the convert is only called once.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' 
             + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Month( column_name )), 2) 
FROM   table
```

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest this user defined function if this what you are going for:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.date_code (@my_date date) RETURNS INT
BEGIN;
    DECLARE @retval int;
    SELECT @retval = CAST(CAST(datepart(year,@my_date) AS nvarchar(4))
                        + CONVERT(CHAR(2),@my_date, 101)
                        + CONVERT(CHAR(2),@my_date, 103) AS int);
    RETURN @retval;
END
go
```

To call it:

```
SELECT dbo.date_code(getdate())
```

It returns as of today

> 20211129

Comment: Take note I did test this functions on days and it does lead the zeros

Answer (score 0):

### Roll your own method

This is a generic approach for left padding anything. The concept is to use REPLICATE to create a version which is nothing but the padded value. Then concatenate it with the actual value, using a isnull/coalesce call if the data is NULLable. You now have a string that is double the target size to exactly the target length or somewhere in between. Now simply sheer off the N right-most characters and you have a left padded string.

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 2) + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, '2012-12-09') AS varchar(2)), 2) AS leftpadded_day
```

### Go native

The [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function offers various methods for obtaining pre-formatted dates. Format 103 specifies `dd` which means leading zero preserved so all that one needs to do is slice out the first 2 characters.

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(2), CAST('2012-12-09' AS datetime), 103) AS convert_day
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @day CHAR(2)

SET @day = right('0'+ cast(day(getdate())as nvarchar(2)),2)

print @day
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
CONVERT(CHAR(2), DATE_COLUMN, 101)
```

to get the month part with 2 characters and

```
CONVERT(CHAR(2), DATE_COLUMN, 103)
```

for the day part.

Comment: what is 101 and 103?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Declare @dateToGet varchar(10)
Set @dateToGet = convert(varchar, getdate(), 112)
```

This works fine for the whole date with leading zeros in month and day

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(GETDATE()AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR);
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(GETDATE()AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR),1,4);
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(GETDATE()AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR),6,2);
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(GETDATE()AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR),9,2);
```

Regards.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres:

`SELECT TO_CHAR(your_timestamp_column, 'MM') FROM your_table;`

Answer (score -1):

select
    right('0000' + cast(datepart(year, GETDATE()) as varchar(4)), 4) + '-'+  + 
    right('00' + cast(datepart(month, GETDATE()) as varchar(2)), 2) + '-'+  + 
    right('00' + cast(datepart(day, getdate()) as varchar(2)), 2) as YearMonthDay

Comment: I suspect you're being downvoted because this is a fairly low quality answer, you didn't even put it in a code block.  Also, I am not entirely sure why you would pad the year with Zeros, but maybe I am missing something.