# Getting Month and Day from a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

It is possible simplify this query (MSSQL)?

```
SELECT RIGHT(STR(MONTH('2014-05-02'))+100,2) + '-' 
+ RIGHT(STR(DAY('2014-05-02'))+100,2)
```

I want month and day from a date but always with leading zeros if only have one digit in the month / day. In this date `2014-05-02` I want only `05-02`. I can do that with this query but I don't know if there is a simply way...

Comment: seems this similar question was already http://stackoverflow.com/a/13804170/1692632

Comment: I take it you actually have a `DATE` column, not a `CHAR` column?

Comment: Yes, it's a `date` column.

Comment: Is this being output to a UI? Why not format it outside the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(5), GETDATE(), 10)
```

Result:

```
05-23
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar(10), GETDATE(), 126), 5)
```

For the example,

```
select RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-5-2'), 126), 5)
```

Comment: what if he has `2014-5-4` ?

Comment: @Darka, The query is intended for to convert a datetime field. If the field is string, then convert to datetime.

Comment: yeap, now I see @TechDo. Just stupid question, it `CONVERT` is related to some format? I mean, can be that server will think that 2 is month and 5 is day?

Comment: @Darka I think... No need to worry since its a date field!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110),5)
```

OR

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 10),5)
```

Both return the same result as follows

```
RESULT: 05-23
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using format.

If you have a string:

```
select format(convert(date, '2014-05-23', 126),'MM-dd');
```

If you have a date:

```
select format(GetDate(),'MM-dd');
```

Answer (score 0):

This could really Help you.

```
DECLARE @A DATETIME = GETDATE()

SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),@A,110)
```

[image]