# Keep only Day from Date in column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

i have created a stored procedure by online help to generate a monthly attendance report

```
    USE [Attendace]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[PerDayAttendance]    Script Date: 04/11/2018 20:16:05 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PerDayAttendance] 
@STARTDATE DATE,  
@ENDDATE DATE  
AS BEGIN
WITH DATERANGE AS
(  
   SELECT DT =DATEADD(DD,0, @STARTDATE)  
   WHERE DATEADD(DD, 1, @STARTDATE) <= @ENDDATE  
   UNION ALL  
   SELECT DATEADD(DD, 1, DT)  
   FROM DATERANGE  
   WHERE DATEADD(DD, 1, DT) <= @ENDDATE  
)  SELECT * INTO cte_DATES  
FROM DATERANGE   
DECLARE @COLUMN varchar(max)
SELECT @COLUMN=ISNULL(@COLUMN+',','')+ '['+ CAST(CONVERT(DATE , T.DT) AS varchar) + ']'  FROM cte_DATES T
DECLARE @Columns2 varchar(max)  
SET @Columns2 = SUBSTRING((SELECT DISTINCT ',ISNULL(['+ CAST(CONVERT(DATE , DT) 
as varchar )+'],'''') AS ['+ CAST(CONVERT(DATE , DT) as varchar )+']' 
FROM cte_DATES GROUP BY dt FOR XML PATH('')),2,8000)  
DECLARE @QUERY varchar(MAX)  
SET @QUERY = 'SELECT P.EID, ENAME, ' + @Columns2 +', Wdays, Holidays, K.Present, (Wdays-(Holidays + K.Present))as Absent, (cast(((s.Salary/Wdays)*(k.present+Holidays)) as numeric(36,0))) as Salary FROM   
(  
SELECT  A.EID, A.ENAME ,  B.DT AS DATE, (Case when cast(A.WorkTime as time) > 
''00:00:00'' then ''P'' else ''Abs'' end) as worktime FROM TblAttendnce  A 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN cte_DATES B 
ON A.EDATE=B.DT
) X  
PIVOT   
(  
MIN([Worktime])  
FOR [DATE] IN (' + @COLUMN + ')  
) P 
Cross apply (select Wdays, Holidays from dbo.fn_Fn1(''' + CAST(@STARTDATE AS VARCHAR(50)) + ''','''+ CAST(@ENDDATE as Varchar(50))+'''))H 
Right Outer Join (select eid, COUNT(present) as present from Attendace.dbo.vwPayroll 
where Edate between ''' + CAST(@STARTDATE AS VARCHAR(50)) + '''and'''+ CAST(@ENDDATE as Varchar(50))+'''
group by eid) as K on K.eid=p.EID
Right Outer Join ((select eid, salary from dbo.employeeMast))as s on S.eid=p.eid
WHERE ISNULL(ENAME,'''')<>''''  
'
Exec (@QUERY)  
DROP TABLE cte_DATES   
END
```

Now the outcome is like this

[image: Please Check the Image]

i need to prepare a crystal report from this procedure, but due to dynamic column header name i am unable to do this.

My Query is how to make column name as 01, 02, 03 instead of 2018-04-01, 2018-04-02, 2018-04-03

i mean i want to rename column name as DD of dd/mm/yyyy

by this way i may able to reflect it in crystal report.

Comment: Please take a look at: [Get day from date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804096/how-do-i-get-the-month-and-day-with-leading-0s-in-sql-e-g-9-09?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

When I am developing a Crystal Report or training a client; I teach them either to rename to the data field in the SQL or stored procedure such date as 3 or Insert a Duplicate Detail line and use the OLD line for Development. Making the NEW Line a Comment Line.

Comment: didn't get you, can I use an alias in above code to define dates column

I am not a professional in coding so I need some example